# Other code branches from MYSQL (than MariaDB and xtractDB)

Tags: mysql, database, open-source, mariadb

Is there a reference list of MYSQL code branches?

I am aware of MYSQL being branched into Percona's xtract DB and also into Maria DB. Since MYSQL is now part of O R A C L E  I could think of other code branches. However via g* I only found those both mentionend. A reference list would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Which MySQL Fork/Version to Pick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450534/which-mysql-fork-version-to-pick) has information on a number of other MySQL forks from 2010 including OurDelta and Drizzle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL also mentions WebScaleSQL which you can find more information on at http://webscalesql.org/

Comment: Thank you for putting together the links. I read similar posts from 3-4 years ago at other places. I wonder if there are diverging trends in the more recent past.